# Comma in web.config string causes silverlight application to hang

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

I have a silverlight application that uses a number of key-value pairs in its Web.config. I recently added a further key-value pair and the application then hung after it had loaded (web-page just showed "100%" and the blue 'loading' animation). I narrowed it down to the fact that the Value part has a comma character within the string. Remove the comma and the application works fine.

I did not think the comma character was special in .config files, certainly not within strings. How do I get a comma in there without breaking it?

Here are the two key-value pairs I recently added. The second one has the comma:

```
<add key="ReferralAllocatedOnly" value="True" />
<add key="ReferralAllocatedOnlyDesc" value="If true, only referrals with an allocated substation will be retrieved" />
```

The second pair is not actually loaded by this application at all! It is used by a separate 'admin' application just to put straight into a tooltip. To get around the issue I have just removed the comma, but I would still like to understand why it caused the problem in the first place.

--- Alistair

Comment: Are you parsing the string value as an array somewhere in your code? It could be helpful if  you post the code in which you are parsing the value from web.config, also the key-value pair could be helpful.

Comment: The string value is not actually used by this application at all! It is there fore a separate 'admin' application to display in a tooltip.